# Replace Empty Strings In A List With A Value

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

If I have a list

```
("foo" "bar" "" "baz")
```

and I need to change any "" to "biz", what is a good way to go about that?

Comment: I'd use `map`, what did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(map #(if (empty? %) "biz" %)
     '("foo" "bar" "" "baz"))
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness, here's an alternate method that uses a more specialized built-in:

```clj
(replace ; Replace all instances of... 
  {"" "biz"} ; "" with "biz"... 
  '("foo" "bar" "" "baz")) ; in the list
```

Which also returns a lazy sequence.

Note that the map given as the first argument can contain multiple entries. If you have multiple replacements, I'd definitely go with `replace` over an explicit `map`.

[`replace` actually just uses `map` behind the scenes](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4998), but uses a map lookup instead of a equality check to do the replacements. I would expect them to preform similarly for one replacement, but for `replace` to be faster for more than once since it doesn't need to do a linear search over all the replacements like you would doing manual `=` checks.